# How to assess if a Magento Developer has the skill to find his way around Magento?

Tags: development

What kind of questions would be relevant and appropriate when hiring a Magento Developer?

The basics aspects should be covered first: clear idea about how internet works (browser, web servers, web arhitecture in general), programming and analytical thinking.

Regarding Magento I believe it's more important to understand how to find your way around Magento, then knowing by heart how you should do things. 
Have a clear idea about how Magento is architected and have this skill (I believe it can be called a skill) to find the things you need.

What are your thoughts on this? How would you test that a developer knows his way around Magento?
I was mislead a few times by asking specific questions and getting the expected answers.

Comment: @Rick Kuipers thanks for the revision man, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8240/questions-to-expect-in-an-interview-for-a-junior-magento-developer-position/8259#8259) given by @philwinkle on what questions to expect when you're taking a Magento job interview. It might help!

Comment: I really wouldn't care if the guy doesn't know about Best Practices or he doesn't have in depth knowledge of Magento (3 types of models and a lot of specific references). I intend to find out if that guy can find the information he needs. I don't really care how much he already knows.

Comment: ah ok, well in that case giving him a set of Magento issues and asking him to find at least 2 articles/posts online with solutions to that article will work. Or asking him how he would debug, for example, a blank page. Any good dev should at least be able to name some options without even knowing the framework (in this case Magento)

Answer (score 0):

May set "Magento Developer Certificate" as a must?

But depends on which Versions you working on. If Enterprise Edition you need a "Magento Developer Plus Certificate".

Comment: I don't think this is an necessary condition. I'm not a certified developer...does that mean I don't know my way around it? :)

Comment: I am not a certified developer. And one of the reasons is that I don't put too much value for that piece of paper (or any piece of paper) that would show someone's skill set.

Comment: No no, you are the best as far as I know :D ... But he said he was missleaded often so I thought this could be an easy way to say "ok, this one has for sure at least that knowledge you nedd for certification"

Comment: I'm not certified as well. Since it's quite expensive to become certified I bet a lot of developers are not

Comment: If you look at other certificates prices, the 250€ for the magento certificate is a joke. But for conclusion, I didnt say anyone is a bad coder because he/she is not certified. It was just an idea how someone can easy ensure some skill.

Comment: Certification certainly helps to get an interview, but it should not be a requirement. If you get two applicants, and only one can get an interview, the certified one would most likely win the spot. I only got certified, as it was offered free by my employer, else I would not have bothered.

Comment: @Marius, you know your way around :). I would think certifications are helpful especially for consulting firms to boast their credentials.

Comment: "It was just an idea how someone can easy ensure some skill" - "the certified one would most likely win the spot". It depends on the role, employers who look for this do not have clear requirements (as in defined) for what they need so use it as a yard stick. In general it means that you will run around, hence why we generally avoid any projects with certification requirements. We leave them for those who want a job (time), not a consultant (knowledge). If you are looking for high profile roles, it makes no difference, for the rest it is a choice which may or may not make the difference.

Comment: FWIW certified developer staff is required for partners.