# Question to expect for a front end magento position

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I have interview coming up and it will be a interview for magento first time,i search SE and i could find one [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8240/questions-to-expect-in-an-interview-for-a-junior-magento-developer-position), but it was for developer. I been working online for magento project but this time i am nervous and want to get the job, so gotta have a good interview. 
So as a magento front end developer, what question should i expect? How much php i should know or should i know,as i am following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/magento-theme-development-home-page-part-2--cms-24653) tutorials and see a lot of php getting changed so should i only know where to find a template and copy it from, while using jQuery, javascript etc. 
Insight would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Magento front-end dev position I would looking these skills:

> **Php**

- Basic:

  - Basic Syntax
  - Print/Echo Variables
  - Call Functions
  - Understand / Handle Controls (if, for, foreach, while etc..)
- Pro (nice to have)

  - Understand Clases (OOP, Hierarchy, Scopes, etc)
  - Basic Knowledge for Blocks Creation/Handling
  - Basic Knowledge to deal with Models / Collections

> **Javascript**

- Basic:

  - Basic Syntax and Concepts
  - jQuery
- Pro:

  - Performance Related Concepts (DOM Processing, Rendering etc)
  - Understanding of Scopes and Encapsulation
  - jQuery Plugins Creation/Modifications
  - Prototype
  - Understanding of Objects Patterns

> **CSS/HTML** *(must be strong here)*

- CSS 2/3
- HTML 4/5 Markup
- Media Query
- Responsive Concepts
- Sass / Compass (4 RWD)

> **Magento**

- **Full Understanding of layouts**
- M(B)VC Magento Implementation
- Block/View Concepts
- Module Configuration - Setup/Data Installs (good for scripting pages)
- CMS Pages and Blocks
- Cache Handling
- Dev Mode / Logging Tools
- Mysql Basic Concepts *(to deal with dumps and some queries)*

> **Magento 2**

- Less
- Require.js
- Grunt
- Composer
- **Hi Yoga/Zen/Ninja level** *to support the pain and drive the rage for the time lost in every change deployment*

> **Others:**

- VCS: Git/Svn
- OS: Minimun Linux Notions (ssh, bash, services etc)
- Some Scrum/Agile Concepts
- Mysql Basic Concepts

Just for reference you always have the [certification guide](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/FEDC_Study_Guide_v.1.0.pdf).

All other items are relative and personal of each one, and are "position" and seniority dependants.

My two Cents :)

Comment: That's, that is a long list. But isn't front end developer limited to js, html and css rather then knowing MVC framework or editing the code of OOP PHP

Comment: Yes but note that I made a separation between basic & pro, with basic should be enough, anyway it depend on the seniority required.

Comment: What would u think, is it a standard of front end developer day to day job to edit and create themes [like] this (https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/magento-theme-development-home-page-part-2--cms-24653)

Comment: if the changes put on server do not reflect. What steps should i take?