# Are there any document or ebook for Magento Certification exam?

Tags: certification

I'm gonna take Magento Certification exam in next 3 months to become a Magento Certified Developer, I've been searching for document for this exam. When I look at the study guide I see a lot of questions which I can answer, however the problem is I don't really know what they are expecting me to answer.

http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Certification-Study-Guide-MCD-v1.pdf

I would like some materials that provide real experience on this exam (it's best if Ebook is written by Magento Certificated developer)

I highly appreciate any suggestion/recommendation on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/81/studying-to-become-a-magento-certified-developer
Also, on the bottom of the stufy guide there are example questions. The test is multiple choice.

Answer (score 2):

I use this atm:

http://blog.belvg.com/category/magento-news/developer-certification

For me, way better then the study guide (I mean the one from the official Magento site)!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ty, I am aware of that but was not sure how to setup the answer for a link where like the 30 sites behind build the answer. You may have an approach for me how you would do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, passed today with 66/70 and heres my new approach:

I recommend to buy one of these : http://www.pass4test.com/search.php?q=magento&x=-939&y=-30

```
Why?
1. It gives you 130 questions AND answers. 70 of them are aktually taken for the test (depens on certificate)
2. It includes a Test-Software for practise
3. You get free updates on your test material if theres an test-update during your practise-time
```

For me, absolutely perfect and an really easy way to pass the Certification