# How to start working in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I am new in magento and a little confused to how to start work in it.
I studied the basics of magento and found its structure really complex.

I never worked on a CMS before and I have a little knowledge of php and html but I am not good in css.

Should I learn the css before start working in magento or it will not be a big problem.

What are the easiest steps for learning magento. Please give me some ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Better you achieve some knowledge in php and then start on Magento

Comment: @user5268 you'r welcome. After you are comfortable with php (including OOp) then refer Magento U training videos http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/on-demand At the same time you can follow Magento knowledgebase tutorials as well. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/81/studying-to-become-a-magento-certified-developer

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you wan't to do. If you just want to start off implementing simple theme's some knowledge of PHP and frontending (HTML, JS, CSS) should be enough.

But if you really want to get down and dirty with customising Magento, extensions and functionality you will need a good grasp on PHP, OOP, MySQL might be handy and Javascript, preferably prototype.

My advice, first get your PHP skills up to speed, afterwards follow some courses on Magento U and start off with a simple shop tweaking some minor stuff. All in all this should keep you busy for the upcoming 6 months. Just doing frontend stuff will take you less time but will limit you to implement theme's and installing extensions without being able to tweak them.

Comment: yes you should brush up your php skills it is the best way to learn the magento easily. It is a bumpy ride to learn the magento.

Answer (score 3):

I have learned  magento [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSxq-eJ0VvY) . This is awesome tutorials, but I had a lot of knowledge about wordpress and php then, so it was easy to adapt to magento. Try to learn html and css. That you will always need.

Happy coding.