# Do you guys have any data about how many Magento Developers FAIL in Magento Certification Exam each month?

Tags: magento-1.9, certification

I am on the way of preparing for Magento Certification Exam.
I really want to know the failing rate of this exam.
Can you share with me this information?

Moreover, do you guys have some source of example questions for this exam?

Answer (score 3):

### Failure Rate

In my knowledge, there is only one **[who revealed the failure in the exam](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125)**. I appreciate @phpahn for that because no one like to disclose a failure in their life. :)

### Think positively

Why do you think negatively in this context? Think positively. If you prepare well, you will definitely going to pass the exam. No doubt in it. Generally the failure rate is too less in this exam. This is because developers will prepare well for this exam. So the failure rate will be less. However I don't have any authoritative proofs for this. But I know it will be less.

### What is essential for success

For a successful pass score, along with good preparation, sufficient working experience in Magento platform is essential. Even if you prepared well, but you have nil experience in Magento, then I swear the exam will be tough for you. But if you have 2 years of experience in Magento atleast, then with a proper preparation you are going to pass the exam easily. Why experience is important here ? Because questions are like that. It demands for the familiarity in the platform rather than the theory and core concept.

### Resources

- Go through this **[magento question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/81/studying-to-become-a-magento-certified-developer)**. You will get lot of resources there.
- My favourite resource is : [**MageCert.com**](http://magecert.com/). It is going to help you a lot.
- **MageStore** give you wonderful [**opportunities to test your skills**](http://magento-quiz.magestore.com/). Use that regularly. It will help you a lot.

Good luck with the exam.

---

<sup>I am a certified developer. It is the experience + preparation which played back in my success. Always think positively. You are going to get it.</sup>

Comment: Good answer @Rajeev,, http://www.magestore.com/magento-certification-study-guides.html and http://blog.belvg.com/category/magento-news/developer-certification is also useful for certification

Comment: @KeyurShah You are right. I didn't emphasise them because they are listed in the first link in my answer. That's why I didnt go further on this. List is endless.

Comment: I didn't saw all answer in first link ,,and ya for Certification Resources are endless :-)

Comment: @KeyurShah the link which I mentioned is this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/81/studying-to-become-a-magento-certified-developer . this is the link which is the first link available under 'resource' heading in my answer

Comment: @RajeevKTomy, thanks so much for your tips and information :D

Comment: @TracyPhung If my answer helped you, please accept this answer by click on the tick sign