# Learning Magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

Hello could you recommend some websites where i could start to learn magento?im a junior dev so i will need to also learn how to create my own extensions/modules. So, anything related to core Magento and module development would be very helpful thanks

Comment: Thank you all for the resources you have recommended I can't upvote since this account is new.

Answer (score 5):

Devdocs will be a good place to start - https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/

There are some courses available on https://m.academy/ and yireo.com both paid and free.

You can also try https://www.mage2.tv/

Also there are some blogs which post magento 2 stuff such as

https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/

https://www.yireo.com/blog

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the best websites for learning along with practical implementations as well. Step by step guide

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

You may start from official document first.

Official document:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/docs

About certified (similar question from here): [Studying to become a Magento Certified Developer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/81/studying-to-become-a-magento-certified-developer)

Others:

https://github.com/run-as-root/awesome-magento2#learning

https://github.com/aleron75/mageres

https://github.com/creatuity/LearningMagento2

https://learningmagento.com

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com

Answer (score 2):

I think the best website to learn Magento is Devdocs the official Magento documentation.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/#home

Then I think the MagePlaza will tell you the basic Concepts.

https://www.mageplaza.com/

This is the site that help you to do some basic tasks :

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/

If you need more help I will also surely available for you here.